# Why is my content script file loaded as an empty file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm creating a Chrome extension which inserts a content script, but the content script appears to be loaded as an empty file.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://stackoverflow.com/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
console.log('hello world');
```

When I go to `chrome-extension://<extension's id>/content_script.js`, I see the correct content of `console.log('hello world');`, but in the browser it appears empty:

[image: empty content_script.js]

And nothing is printed to the console. Does anyone know what can cause this?

Also, I tried adding some more files and folders. All the files and folders appear in the sources tab, but all the files are empty.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case, the reason Chrome refused to read `content.js` is that the file was an alias (I was using `ln -s`). Copy the original file to the extension folder solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Saw that too a few times on Chrome dev channel, it started a few months ago, obviously a bug.

Try restarting the browser.
Try adding `debugger;` in the code.
Try specifying `"run_at": "document_start"` (or `document_end`) in [the content script declaration](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at).

Comment: Tried all 3, unfortunately none of them changed anything.

Comment: @Oak, go to the devtools settings, `Manage framework blackboxing`, see if `[ ] Blackbox content scripts` is unchecked. Also try reproducing in a freshly created Chrome user profile.

Comment: It's unchecked. Tried with a fresh user profile, didn't help either.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for trying!

Comment: note restarting chrome requires to do file+exit, not just closing all windows.

Comment: needed a restart on mine... (Chrome v92)